# Use same host's keyboard shortcuts on VM to copy/paste text

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware-fusion

Does there exist a way to make copy/paste working into a virtual machine (not between the VM and the host) using the same keyboard shortcuts used by the host machine?

In practice in macOS (host) I use cmd+C and cmd+V, respectively to copy and paste, while working with the VMs I have always used shift+ctrl+C and shift+ctrl+V for these operations. My doubt is about if it is possible to set the use of cmd+C and cmd+V to copy and paste when I am into the VM.

I had not able to do this neither using Virtualbox nor with VMware Fusion.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or AskDifferent (link at the bottom of this page).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I reopen this topic, because here it had two thumbs up (so it seems other people in this community are interested about the topic). Moreover this is not a UNIX question, so probably it should be out of contest even on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The fact I am using an UNIX system (macOS) is not relevant, I noticed the same issue on Windows too (I did not tried on any Linux distro neither Virtualbox nor VMware Fusion although). On Windows are a bit different the shortcuts but the problem is just the same, I cited macOS just to bring the issue in a practical context.

Comment: The point is, you aren't asking a programming question. See the first link I posted in my first comment.

Comment: I saw it, a little insight to support my decision to post here: if you search for questions with the tags I have used on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ compared to here these are the results in number of searches
virtual-machine -> stackoverflow 77,839 - unix.stackexchange 1,433
virtualbox -> stackoverflow 29,622 - unix.stackexchange 1,566
keyboard-shortcuts -> stackoverflow 28,427 - unix.stackexchange 1,540
vmware-fusion -> stackoverflow 1,155 - unix.stackexchange 105

Numbers are telling that probably this is the best place where people are interested about the topic :)

Comment: It doesn't matter. Off topic is off topic and it will get closed.